# Cancel button not working in hosted form of authorize.net CIM

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

Cancel button has a function `btnCancelEdit_onclick(g_paymentItemEditInfo, 999)` which is generated during runtime. If I call the `AuthorizeNetPopup.openAddPaymentPopup()` pop up the cancel button does not work.

If I call the and have made the necessary changes which work fine if i call `AuthorizeNetPopup.openManagePopup()` first and then open `AddPaymentPopup` popup, but does not work when I call `AuthorizeNetPopup.openAddPaymentPopup()` directly the cancel button works. I know it is not possible to change the function of the cancel button at runtime, is there any other option?

I have seen this [link](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/CIM-hosted-form-option-popup-won-t-close-on-cancel-or-suscessful/td-p/13146) and have made the necessary changes which work fine if I call `AuthorizeNetPopup.openManagePopup()` first and then open AddPaymentPopup popup, but does not work when I call `AuthorizeNetPopup.openAddPaymentPopup()` directly.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Not really its something which we cannot change on our end, it has to be done on authorize.net side.